# jQuery - What's wrong with that code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've onclick jquery code that doesn't give any response even with an error!

I don't know why, but here's my **jQuery Code**:

```
/* This Is working correctly */
$(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group select").on("change", function() {
  var tagsUl = '<li class="' + $(this).val() + '"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + $(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group select option:selected").text() + '</li>';
  $(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group ul").append($(tagsUl));
  $(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group select option:selected").remove();
});

/* This isn't working correctly */
$(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group ul li i").on("click", function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).parent().attr("class"),
    optionText = $(this).parent().text(),
    appendedOption = "<option value='" + $(optionValue) + "'>" + $(optionText) + "</option>";
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("select").append($(appendedOption));
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I'm 100% sure that this element selector exist
when I open the css element inspector, select the element and put the same element selector, it shows that this element is the selected one.

anyway, here's my **HTML Code**:

```
<article class='add-blog'>
  <div class='blog-add-form'>
    <div class='add-article'>
      <form method='POST' action='example.php' class='form-horizontal'>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <select></select>
          <ul class='list-unstyled selected-ul'>
            <li class='0'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-times'></i> Anytext</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: It's not likely to be the cause of your issue but your HTML code is malformed. No closing tag for article.

Comment: There's already a closing tag but stackoverflow removes it for some reason

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: This is the first thing I've done

Comment: @collapsar Hema_Elmasry said that didn't be errors.

Comment: Hema_Elmasry - You didn't have it marked up as code, so SO was ignoring it (because markdown allows some HTML tags). I've fixed the markup for you. But @jota3 is still correct in that the HTML is incorrect, you have an extra `</div>`.

Comment: Ok, thanks
It wasn't changing, now It changed

Comment: I've updated the post with the full jQuery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved


Thanks to everyone who helped me in solving this problem !
When you guys have told me that the code is working fine with you,
I knew that the problem isn't from the onclick jQuery function.
My new code :

```
$(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group select").on("change", function() {
  var tagsUl = '<li class="' + $(this).val() + '"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + $(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group select option:selected").text() + '</li>';
  $(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group ul").append($(tagsUl));
  $(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group select option:selected").remove();
$(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group ul li i").on("click", function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).parent().attr("class"),
    optionText = $(this).parent().text(),
    appendedOption = "<option value='" + optionValue + "'>" + optionText + "</option>";
  $("select").append(appendedOption);
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `append()` function argument with the function `$`, just write `$("select").append(appendedOption);`.

Comment: You can mark your answer as the correct one. It removes the question from the `unanswered` questions as well as helps future readers.

Comment: I just have to wait 2 days to mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are casting your `optionValue` and `optionText` to another jQuery object when you add them to `appendOption`. Remove the `$()` around `optionValue` and `optionText` and it should work.

```js
$(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group ul li i").on("click", function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).parent().attr("class");
  var optionText = $(this).parent().text();
  var appendedOption = "<option value='" + optionValue + "'>" + optionText + "</option>";
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("select").append($(appendedOption));
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<article class='add-blog'>
  <div class='blog-add-form'>
    <div class='add-article'>
      <form method='POST' action='example.php' class='form-horizontal'>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <select></select>
          <ul class='list-unstyled selected-ul'>
            <li class='0'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-times'></i> Anytext</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry You will need to provide more insights on how to reproduce the issue as this solution seems to fix the bug.

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry What `Still is the same thing`? What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: When I click on the icon,
Nothing happens
No errors, nothing

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot reproduce what you are experiencing. I've tried multiple browsers and all of them are clickable. Others, have also confirmed that it is working for them. It might be specific to your setup you have.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass to the `jQuery` function (`$`) a string, and it interept it as a selector:

```
appendedOption  = "<option value='" + $(optionValue) + "'>" + $(optionText) + "</option>";
```

Instead, do it as follows:

```
appendedOption  = "<option value='" + optionValue + "'>" + optionText + "</option>";
```

```js
$(".add-blog .blog-add-form .add-article .input-group ul li i").on("click", function() {
    var optionValue     = $(this).parent().attr("class"),
        optionText      = $(this).parent().text(),
        appendedOption  = "<option value='" + optionValue + "'>" + optionText + "</option>";
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("select").append(appendedOption);
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class='add-blog'>
  <div class='blog-add-form'>
    <div class='add-article'>
      <form method='POST' action='example.php' class='form-horizontal'>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <select></select>
          <ul class='list-unstyled selected-ul'>
            <li class='0'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-times'></i> Anytext</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: That's certainly true, but wouldn't account for the OP's symptom. Best to wait to answer until/unless the OP provides a more complete example.

Comment: Ok,
But why when I try to test the click function with only the remove(); code
It doesn't even give a response ?

Comment: I've added a snippet.

Comment: If the only change is `optionValue` instead of `$(optionValue)`, this isn't the problem (though, again, it's **a** problem :-) ). With `$(optionValue)` it would work just as it does in your snippet, but with the text `[object Object]` as the value.

Comment: maybe he wanted to use template literals ` string ${variable/expression} string`

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry And this code isn't working? What is the problem?

Comment: I've posted the new code
The problem was that I had to include the second on click function on the first on change function